# Rails application not recognizing migration, but rails console does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've just migrated my model to have new attributes and the application itself is creating objects with the old schema.

Application (in a controller):

```
@editable_field = Spree::EditableField.new
puts @editable_field
# {"id":null,"product_id":null,"coordinates":null,"label":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

Console:

```
@editable_field = Spree::EditableField.new
puts @editable_field
# => {"id"=>nil, "product_id"=>nil, "text"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "x"=>nil, "y"=>nil, "width"=>nil, "height"=>nil}
```

The latter is correct.

Comment: Did you restart the `rails server` after running the migration?

Comment: Application in development?  if you're using the `spring` gem sometimes that prevents changed models from being reloaded... it shouldn't but it does.  Try `spring stop` then restart `rails s`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn This was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring` gem (a rails application preloader) is designed to speed up loading of files in development, but sometimes works unexpectedly.

If you're ever in doubt whether changed files are being loaded, try `spring stop` before you restart your server or console.